# What alternatives to VNC are there for Linux?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

Are there (preferably free) alternatives to VNC on Linux?

Is there different remote desktop technologies for Linux or is it all based around VNC?

EDIT:
Thanks symcbean for your comment, good point. I find the network performance of RDP much faster than VNC. I am currently using tightVNC, but I do not want to compromise the quality for speed. Using RDP I find that it is just like being infront of the computer. I'm using VNC over an internet connection to a virtual dedicated server, on a broadband connection (admittedly not the fasted broadband in the world - but fast enough) - so in theory there isn't really any serious bottle necks.

-thanks
Alex.

Comment: There are answers below - but it might help to know what you don't like about VNC

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have a reasonable fast link, X11 is the native remote technology on Linux and every other Unix-type system, as the X11 system was designed from the ground up to work over the network. These days, it's mostly used with ssh port forwarding (like `ssh yourname@example.com -X`), and NX, mentioned in the answer by alvosu, "merely" improves on the compression, making it accessible over slow links with a high latency.

Comment: X11 would be much more secure also, using SSHD, since VNC and xrdp may be (I believe) unencrypted unless you buy a 3rd party version of those protocols like "Real-VNC" , etc.

Comment: Just like you can tunnel X11 over SSH, you can also tunnel VNC over SSH (or SSL/TLS; look at stunnel) ;)

Comment: X11 over ssh *feels* about 5 times faster than VNC or Spice -- nearly fast enough to view flash video...

Answer (score 12):

[NX technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) is a computer program that handles remote X Window System connections, and attempts to greatly improve on the performance of the native X display protocol to the point that it can be usable over a slow link such as a dial-up modem.
[FreeNX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freenx.berlios/) - Free Software (GPL) Implementation of the NX Server.

Answer (score 7):

[X2Go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:newtox2go) is a software that enables you to access graphical desktop of a Linux computer. It performs really well even over low bandwidth connections. You can choose to use an entire desktop, or have only a single application (over X11 with a persistent session). If you are familiar with solutions like [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) for command line sessions, X2Go is a similar tool for graphical sessions. X2Go uses [NX technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Depends why you need it.  xrdp is a wrapper around vnc but it solves most of the difficulties I have with vnc on Linux.  http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: interesting I haven't heard of that before - thanks.

Answer (score 5):

And if the box you are connecting to virtualized using KVM (or RHEV), you can use Spice which performs exceptionally well.

http://spice-space.org

Comment: Interesting thanks Izap. I don't have my virtual server setup at the moment, but next time I do I'll give this one a shot. I've not heard of spice before, but it does look intriguing.

Answer (score 2):

Using cygwin-x to run an x-server on your windows, then ssh to the machine.  This doesn't give you a desktop like you would with vncserver, but it lets you run x-apps.  And as mentioned above it is over ssh so it's encrypted. I have not tried running vnc over ssh itself. A tutorial on that would be great.  This is the tutorial for cygwin x 
http://geekswing.com/geek/linux/vncserver-alternative-running-x-windows-through-ssh-using-cygwin-x/

Comment: Good tip, thanks Scotty I haven't had a chance to try it out, but I like the theory.

Comment: Putty (ssh) + Xming was a better alternative to Cygwin (forwarding console and X desktop apps). Putty+Xvsrv is a better alternative now. Find a tutorial including x11 forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome remote desktop looks like a good alternative. 
https://chrome.google.com/remotedesktop